# count(*) column to the right of the data?

Tags: mysql, database, count

Whenever i pull out data using count from my MySQL db, it always places the count column as the left most column.

e.g.

query: `select count(*),name from db.db group by name order by name desc`

gets:

```
count(*) | name
-----------------
23       | Andy
65       | Bob
12       | Chris
```

Is there a way to have it like this?:

```
name | count(*)
-----------------
Andy | 23
Bob  | 65
Chris| 12
```

Comment: Did you ever tried just to invert the list of selected columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch name and count in your select

```
select name,count(*) from db.db group by name order by name desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to invert your count and your colimn name to have a different order

```
select name, count(*) from db.db group by name order by name desc
```

The order you will give to column in SELECT queries will be the order of returned columns

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
select name, count(*) from db.db group by name order by name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM db.db GROUP BY name ORDER BY name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your output sequence like this :

```
query: select name,count(*) from db.db group by name order by name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,count(*) as cnt from db.db group by name order by name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT NAME,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM db.db GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY NAME DESC
```